# How to create this Top border clipper in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, clipper

**The clipper I want to create**
[image: the clipper I want to create]

The code I have tried, but didn't give me the same result as the design clipper.

```dart
 class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
     
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        var path = Path();
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(0, 40);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, 0, size.width / 2, 0);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - size.width / 4, 0, size.width, 40);
        path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
        path.lineTo(0, size.height);
        return path;
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
        return true;
      }
    }
```